# How to create procedure in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to convert Oracle to PostgreSQL. I'm getting error like ****ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UPDATE_USER_PWD_INVALID1***"* while creating procedure

```
 CALL PROCEDURE UPDATE_USER_PWD_INVALID1 IS
      -- PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      V_INVALID_COUNT USERSMPININVALID.INVALID_COUNT%TYPE;
```

Comment: Do you need to **call** or **create** ?

Comment: i called procedure UPDATE_USER_PWD_INVALID1

Comment: this not a valid call statement

Comment: CALL insert_data(1, 2);
read the doc here --
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html

Comment: I want to know how calling the procedure can be done in PostgreSQL

Comment: @snehapai [call](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-call.html)  is used to - well - call a procedure. But your incomplete code example seems to show the code to _create_  a new procedure which is something totally different than calling one.